# How can I redirect to an ASP.NET MVC page with extended session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

**Scenario**

We have an application which has a session timeout of 20 minutes. However we have a requirement in which users must be able to access a certain page in the site for 8 hours after the original(20 minute) session was created. The page in question needs to use the session ID of the original session to pull saved session variables from the database which it can use to perform multiple features

**Potential Ideas**

1. Storing the session ID in a cookie which has an expiry of 8 hours after the original session was created and using this to pull data from the database - I decided against this as it is not advised to store session ID's in cookies as someone could intercept it.
2. Store the session ID in cache - same issue as above
3. Create a new MVC application for the page with an 8 hour session in IIS and when user hits the link to go to the page, it will link to thew new application and it will create a new, separate session which lasts 8 hours - This is the current solution which the legacy Classic ASP application uses. I am hesitant to use this route as I think it is wasteful and time consuming and much more difficult to do in MVC than it is Classic ASP

Does anyone have any ideas to how this requirement can be met, securely?

Comment: its 2018! why do you have a stateful webpage?!?!?

Comment: It's just one of the business requirements to allow users to access a page after the "original" session timeout expires. I dislike it but I can't do anything about it

Comment: so are you asking "whats the best way to design this feature" or "are there any hacky tricks I can do to avoid refactoring"

Comment: Best way to design the feature

Comment: get rid of sessions entirely, have a 1 month expiry on a auth2 refresh token, a 20min expiry auth token and store a created date which you check for your 8 hour limit before serving the special page

Comment: What's the hack? ;)

Comment: make sure the session is on a db, extend the timeout to 8h, redirect to login if you hit a normal page after 20min

Comment: That's a proper hack. Wouldnt be surprised if it crashed the server

Comment: should be ok as long as you off load the sessions

Comment: Is this question primarily concerned with preserving session state variables? Or are you only concerned with keeping the user in an authenticated state? These are very different requirements, and one does not require the other.

Comment: Preserving session state variables

Comment: Regarding 1, how do you think session works? There already is a cookie with session id.

Comment: I understand how the session works but the company wants to have a special page that can be accessed for 8 hours after the first click of the page, regardless if the 20 mins session ended.

Comment: Then I don't understand you worry about keeping sessionId in cookie when it is already there. In any case it would probably be better to generate you own key to put in cookie instead of reusing session

Comment: Because the session only lasts for 20 minutes and the page I need to access must be available for 8 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deal with a similar issue in an app (super long log-in state), and resolved it by storing a GUID in a cookie on the client (via HttpOnly cookie) that is tied to a single login event record on the server.

Technically if someone had physical access to a logged in machine, they could see the cookie and copy the GUID value to be used elsewhere but if they did that, then they already have access to the logged in machine so its pointless to worry about anyway.

Comment: If the site was hosted on the internet then a malicious user without physical access to the machine could also get the cookie GUID value. I like this idea as the page in question doesn't allow the user to do anything damaging anyway

Comment: @Andrew could you elaborate on how the cookie could be compromised? In my app, a compromised login is basically harmless, but I'd like to understand the risks more.

Comment: If your app doesn't use HTTPS, the cookie will be sent unencrypted and anyone who is watching the web traffic could see the value of the cookie being sent. For more info look up "Session Hijacking"

Comment: The site is definitely on HTTPS. "HttpOnly" is a setting a the cookie level that prevents scripts like JavaScript from accessing the cookie, it can only be read by the server-side code.

Answer (score 1):

You could just increase the session timeout to 8 hours for all pages. Then you could just do your own "soft-expire" when someone accesses a page after 21 minutes where session should have been expired.

This soft-expire logic could just be placed in global.asax in Application_BeginRequest

Comment: you sir, are a genius!! ps. remember the session db bit or the server will run out of memory

Comment: I dont like the idea of modifying my whole application for this one page though, I prefer the cookie idea

Comment: Just pray your app pool doesn't recycle during those 8 hours. Probably not a great design if you ever need to be able to restart your services.

Comment: Memory is cheap. The redis session state provider works quite well.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I will go with this solution